# Building the Linux kernel to set up riscv32

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, riscv, riscv32

I was trying to build the kernel from the linux repo v5.12 to set up an image for the qemu emulator and I keep getting this error

```
./arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h: Assembler messages:
./arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:28: Error: unrecognized opcode `csrc 0x100,2', extension `zicsr' required
./arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:16: Error: unrecognized opcode `csrr a5,0x100', extension `zicsr' required
./arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:28: Error: unrecognized opcode `csrc 0x100,2', extension `zicsr' required
./arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:16: Error: unrecognized opcode `csrr a5,0x100', extension `zicsr' required
./arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:22: Error: unrecognized opcode `csrs 0x100,2', extension `zicsr' required
./arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:16: Error: unrecognized opcode `csrr a5,0x100', extension `zicsr' required
./arch/riscv/include/asm/irqflags.h:22: Error: unrecognized opcode `csrs 0x100,2', extension `zicsr' required
```

Any help on how to fix this?

I ran  `make ARCH=riscv CROSS_COMPILE=riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-`
to compile the kernel using the cross compiler

Comment: what configuration did you use? I tried the same after using a default configuration with `make rv32_defconfig ARCH=riscv CROSS_COMPILE=riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-` and it worked

Comment: I did deconfig too. I ran the command ```make ARCH=riscv CROSS_COMPILE=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu- defconfig```

Comment: Your last comment shows a tool-chain for riscv 64 bit, while your post shows riscv 32 bit, did you mix both by accident?

Comment: I am sorry. I used the riscv32 bit toolchain when I was getting the above error. I did ```make ARCH=riscv CROSS_COMPILE=riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu- defconfig```. The last comment was incorrect.

Comment: HI, I am facing the same issue with riscv64, did this get resolved ? Thanks

Comment: I don't remember facing this issue when building riscv64. But I couldn't resolve the issue for riscv32